# Scala 3, missing lines in coverage report

Tags: scala, unit-testing, code-coverage, scala-3

I'm facing a weird issue while generating coverage report for a Scala 3 project.

Following is an example of how report looks like a method:

[image]

because of some reason it is marking statements as uncovered (especially when they are in `for` comprehension )

NOTE: `s3.list` returns `Try[Vector[S3ObjectSummary]]` and my test-case generates both failure and success case.

I'm using `sbt-scoverage` plugin (v 2.0.0). My scala version is 3.2.2.

Report is generated via `sbt clean coverage test coverageReport` command.